# How to deserialize json string to specific object using mapping rules in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

**Business Entity**

```
public class GenericDocument
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public string SupplierAddress { get; set; }
    public string SupplierIban { get; set; }
}
```

**JSON Samples**

```
{ 
   "invoiceDate" : "2021-10-12",
   "vendorName": "just a test",
   "vendorAddres": "just a vendor address",
   "vendorVat": "just a vendor vat"
}

{ 
   "docDate" : "2021-10-12",
   "sellerName": "just a test",
   "sellerAddres": "just a vendor address",
   "sellerVat": "just a vendor vat"
}
```

**API**

```
        public class DocumentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateDocument([FromBody] DocumentCreateRequest document)
        {
            var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<GenericDocument>>(Convert.ToString(document.Documents),
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                    { ContractResolver = new DocumentSerializeContractResolver(document.SerializeDic) });

            return Ok();
        }
    }

    public class DocumentCreateRequest
    {
        public IDictionary<string, string> SerializeDic { get; set; }
        public dynamic Documents { get; set; }
    }

public class DocumentSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> MapDictionary { get; set; }

    public DocumentSerializeContractResolver(IDictionary<string, string> defaultStringValue)
    {
        this.MapDictionary = defaultStringValue;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        // Set all string properties to have a default value of "this is a default value"
        foreach (var property in properties.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            property.DefaultValue = MapDictionary[property.PropertyName];
            property.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate;

        }
        return properties;
    }
}

public class StringValueProvider : IValueProvider
{
    private PropertyInfo _targetProperty;
    private string _substitutionValue;

    public StringValueProvider(PropertyInfo targetProperty, string substitutionValue)
    {
        _targetProperty = targetProperty;
        _substitutionValue = substitutionValue;
    }

    // SetValue gets called by Json.Net during deserialization.
    // The value parameter has the original value read from the JSON;
    // target is the object on which to set the value.
    public void SetValue(object target, object value)
    {
        _targetProperty.SetValue(target, value);
    }

    // GetValue is called by Json.Net during serialization.
    // The target parameter has the object from which to read the value;
    // the return value is what gets written to the JSON
    public object GetValue(object target)
    {
        object value = _targetProperty.GetValue(target);
        return value == null ? _substitutionValue : value;
    }
}
```

**Request object**

```
{
   "DeserializeRules":"some rules here",
   "DocumentJson":[
      {
         "docDate":"2021-10-12",
         "sellerName":"just a test",
         "sellerAddres":"just a vendor address",
         "sellerVat":"just a vendor vat"
      },
      {
         "docDate":"2021-10-12",
         "sellerName":"just a test",
         "sellerAddres":"just a vendor address",
         "sellerVat":"just a vendor vat"
      },
      {
         "docDate":"2021-10-12",
         "sellerName":"just a test",
         "sellerAddres":"just a vendor address",
         "sellerVat":"just a vendor vat"
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I deserialize any json based on some kind of mapping rules?

The mapping rules are simple "if you find docDate, map it to Date"

How do I access document.Documents in the ContractResolver, in order to take the values and populate the new model.

Comment: What do you mean by "mapping rules"? Is that as simple as "if you see docDate, you will map this to Date" or does it include transformations too? Do you have to cater for nested objects? What about arrays with nested objects? I suggest you edit the question with your intended rules, so that it's clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Llama yes, "if you see docDate, you will map this to Date", no nested objects or arrays

Comment: If you're using JSON.NET, you could maybe create a `ContractResolver` that accepts a `Dictionary<string, string>` and then you could create a "key":"value" mapping rules object which would deserialize to that dictionary.

Comment: @Llama maybe you can share a link with a small example?